# How to manage orientation in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, orientation, android-context

I'm using a drawer with multiple fragments in both orientation, now I want to lock the orientation of one screen, so I'm using this:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but when this fragment comes on screen the whole app lock in portrait (because its using drawer activity context so each fragment get locked).

Comment: when you set orientation it default sets to activity only. So if you need to set different orientation for different fragments just call the above line of code which you used when you are changing fragments.

Comment: @NARESH REDDY yes, i'm already using this line inside the fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use this code only in Activity So you are using the Drawer Layout in your Main activity I think So you set this code in your MainActivity that will work definitely....

```
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

You just put this code .where you created the drawer layout activity...